# A Science Fiction novel regarding Earth, the Moon & Venus

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read a novel, when I was quite young, about some Earth people picked up by Venusians and transported to a dome base on the Moon. There was an accident and the dome was breached. I think they then went on to Venus.

The spacecraft they used were a small craft called a Vimana, and a bigger type of ship called a Vunu. I think the story was meant for a young audience because it was in our school library.

The Venusians were tall, willowy people with long flowing blond hair, I think.

Has anyone any idea what the title is, and the name of the author?

Comment: We don't know when you were young. When did you read the novel, and when do you think it might have been written? What language was it it and what country was it published in? Can you think of any other clues that might help us?

Answer (score 5):

[By Space Ship to the Moon: A Tale of Adventure in Outer Space for Boys](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?564504) by Gavin Gibbons

> an exciting story of two boys taken on a journey to the moon by some
> of the inhabitants of Venus who were visiting the earth in a scout
> ship

[Bookseller: The Organ of the Book Trade, Issues 2750-2766](https://books.google.com/books?id=hNsaAAAAMAAJ)

From [Astounding Science-fiction, Volume 62, Issues 4-63](https://books.google.com/books?id=DU0EAAAAYAAJ) review for Gibbons' nonfiction book [The Coming of the Space Ships](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1805879):

> The author here coins a series of names for various types of UFO,
> which I listed in reviewing his other book, and which seem to have
> been adopted by the occultist wing of saucerdom much as the
> Adamski-model saucer has been.

> ...Mr. Gibbons' terminology offers names for four different types of
> UFO. One, his "vimana," is the common small Adamski-type scout craft
> with three landing globes under a lampshadelike body, and a crew of
> three or four various-sized men..."Vunu" are cigar-shaped mother
> ships about one hundred feet long, like illuminated recorders, which
> may act as ferries in the vicinity of planets. They spawn swarms of
> vimana.

Comment: @user14111 you're right, I didn't notice that. I found now that "By Space Ship to the Moon" is "An exciting story of two boys taken on a journey to the moon by some of the inhabitants of Venus who were visiting the earth in a scout ship". And from "Astounding Science-fiction" again: "The author here coins a series of names for various types of UFO, which I listed in reviewing his other book, and which seem to have been adopted by the occultist wing of saucerdom much as the Adamski-model saucer has been." Can you add it as another answer?

Comment: @user14111 Okay, I did that (I thought it would be stealing from you and also self-vandalism (from what I read on meta)).